# Execute Instructions From The Heap

Tags: c++, c

Can I allocate a block on the heap, set its bytes to values that correspond to a function call and its parameters, then use the function call and dereference operators to execute that sequence?

Comment: This is what a compiler does all the time - what makes you think that you would not be able to do it?

Comment: this is possible in Von Neumann arch but not Harvard arch, generally.

Comment: the Harvard architecture is exceptionally rare - although this is exactly the level where you might encounter it. the vast majority of computers, phones, game consoles etc. use Von Neumann... at least conceptually, regardless as to caches, ROMs or etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So if I read you right you want to dynamically create CPU assembly instructions on the heap and execute them. A bit like self-modifying code. In theory that's possible, but in practice maybe not.

The problem is that the heap is in a data segment, and CPU's/operating systems nowadays have measures to prevent exactly this kind of behavior (it's called the NX bit, or No-eXecute bit for x86 CPUs). If a segement is marked as NX, you can't execute code from it. This was invented to stop computer virusses from using buffer overflows to place exectuable code in data/heap/stack memory and then try the calling program to execute such code.

Note that DLL's and libraries are loaded in the **code** segment, which of course allows code execution.

Comment: You understand what I am getting at.

Comment: This answer is a little confused. The heap lives in the data segment? The segments in a PE file are simply not used this way. The heap does not live in a data segment... more generally the 'code segment' will be loaded into executable memory and most OSs provide a mechanism to allocate such memory - although it might be hidden and buried it must exist.

Comment: You have to make a distinction between how the CPU defines segments and your linker. For modern x86 processors, there are 6 segment descriptors (usually shortened to 'segment'), labelled CS for code, SS for stack, and DS, ES, FS and GS for data. Your program's heap lives in of the data segments. Compiled object files also have 'segments', but they are simply used to define parts that are code (a.k.a. the 'text segment'), static initialized data ('data') and unitialized data (BSS segment). There is no heap in your object files or executable.

Comment: isn't this stuff massively deprecated since the time of 286, 386 and COM? my memory of this is that its a mechanism to extend the address range beyond 16-bits and provide some protection as you describe - but that it has been completely abandoned for the x64 architecture... let me see if i can find some intel document. :)

Comment: tbh, the documentation is quite deep. i should definitely read that ia32/64 manual more so that I know precisely what i am talking about with reference. there are many links that suggest what i say from googling 'x64 segments', but they aren't intel manuals... :)

Comment: @jheriko I came back across this question while I was poking around my history.  I was asking it in principle.  I was actually working on a RAD750 [ppc] board, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. How else could [Dynamic loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) and [Linking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linking) work? Remembering that some (most?) Operating Systems, and some (most?) Linkers are also written in C/C++. For example,

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
void* initializer = dlsym(sdl_library,"SDL_Init");
if (initializer == NULL) {
    // report error ...
} else {
    // cast initializer to its proper type and use
}
```

Also, I believe that a [JIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) (e.g. [GNU lightning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_lightning) and others) in general performs those operations.

Comment: Note that operating systems may impose restrictions on what you can do. For example, you may need to register your code with the OS so it knows what to do if an interrupt or exception or signal occurs while the code is running.

Comment: Not sure what you're getting at by saying "Perhaps." Are you saying that you doubt such restrictions exist?

Comment: @RaymondChen I'm saying it depends on the OS, and if you're writing an OS, or a dynamic linker, or a dynamic loader, or a dynamic translator (e.g. JIT) then you'll be doing this regardless of the "host" OS. Perhaps there are other circumstances as well.

Comment: clearly they do exist, and are highly specific to the situation. ranging from completely impossible in a Harvard Arch to very easy in a system that has a built in dynamic loader.

Answer (score 2):

In windows, for example, this is now very hard to do when it was once very easy. I used to be able to take an array of bytes in C and then cast it to a function pointer type to execute it... but not any more.

Now, you can do this if you can call Global or VirtualAlloc functions and specifically ask for executable memory. On most platforms its either completely open or massively locked down. Doing this sort of thing on iOS, for example, is a massive headache and it will cause a submission fail on the app store if discovered.

here is some fantastically out of date and crusty code where i did the original thing you described:

https://code.google.com/p/fridgescript/source/browse/trunk/src/w32/Code/Platform_FSCompiledCode.cpp

using bytes from https://code.google.com/p/fsassembler

you may notice in there that i need to provide platform (windows) specific allocation functions to get some executable memory:

https://code.google.com/p/fridgescript/source/browse/trunk/src/w32/Core/Platform_FSExecutableAlloc.cpp

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you must ensure that the memory is marked executable. How you do that depends on the architecture.