# Is it possible to execute a machine code stored in a variable?

Tags: c#, c++, .net

Is it possible to store a program (either a .NET targeting or pure machine code) in a byte array and later put it directly into memory and execute it (i.e. by creating a new process)? Does the program have to have kernel access or can it run in user mode?

Can this be achieved using C# and/or C++?

Comment: In C++ this is going to be near-impossible because of modern CPU-level and OS-level protections ([Source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20233289/execute-instructions-from-the-heap#20233427))

Comment: I believe this is actually possible, but you'll probably need admin privileges and/or some assembly code to move data around and/or relatively deep knowledge about how the OS works with different storage types (executable and non-exexutable).

Comment: It's called process hollowing. And it is possible, just difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about machine code, but you can easily do this with .NET code.

There are two methods you can do to generate assemblies at run time. The first is [CodeDom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx) which is the older method of doing it. The second is using the Roslyn via the [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/) NuGet package.

Here is a decent [article](https://keestalkstech.com/2016/05/how-to-add-dynamic-compilation-to-your-projects/) that does a "Hello World" example using both compilers.

When you create assemblies with this method the assemblies if started from your program (either as a stand alone exe or as a dll that is loaded) will have the same access rights as your program.

**EDIT:** if you already have a compiled .net assembly you would like to load that is stored in a variable you only need to call [`Assembly.Load(byte[])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h538bck7(v=vs.110).aspx) and pass in your byte array

```
byte[] data = //...
var assembly = Assembly.Load(data);
dynamic instance = assembly.CreateInstance("YourNamespace.SomeClass"); //assuming the constructor "public SomeClass()" exists.
intance.Run(); //assuming the function "public void SomeClass.Run()" exists.
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. it's possible with by using the [CodeDom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx), but it's not a good idea. By example a user could build a string that would damage your hard drive.

Comment: *"By example a user could build a string that would damage your hard drive."* Not really, the code would run in process, it can't do anything your program can't do already

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Oh, glad i learned something new. Artem, maybe you should take a look about Reflection.Emit. It has some advantages and disadvantages compared to the CodeDom. Didn't have time to take a closer look.

Comment: @CallMeLeonardo, Thank you for the tips! +1